# Couchbase Sync gateway - File upload as attachment

Tags: node.js, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

How can i upload an image file to couchbase from node js using Sync-gateway

The couchbase image document should look like below format after upload

> ```
> >  "_attachments": {
> >         "blahblahblah.jpeg": {
> >           "content_type": "image/jpg",
> >           "digest": "blahblahblah",
> >           "length": 99999,
> >           "revpos": 1,
> >           "stub": true
> >         }
> ```

NB: Couchbase version is Community Edition 5.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what is the version of your couchbase and SGW?
the correct form for inserting attachments is throw Sync gateway
you need check REST API Sync gateway in the documentation of couchbase

in other way you can try convert image in base 64 and set a field in document with string 
this throw SDK for NODE JS

Comment: Thanks . 
Couchbase version is 
Community Edition 5.0.0

Comment: i suppose you have 1.5  SGW here is the documentation
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/references/sync-gateway/rest-api/index.html?v=1.5#/attachment/put__db___doc___attachment_